# history add of Zsh give no clue

Tags: zsh, history

Bash `history -s` is to be done equivalent history in Zsh but
how come `history add` of Zsh give no clue

```
% history add printf "FOO" 
fc: event not found: add
```

So confusing documentation hint it `history add`, please really help out.

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/651679/how-do-i-add-a-command-to-zsh-history or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/651679/how-do-i-add-a-command-to-zsh-history for ways to do this in Zsh.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's old, but here is the answer. Found it in [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/651679/how-do-i-add-a-command-to-zsh-history).

> You can use print -s or print -S for this:
>
> > `-s`
> >
> > Place the results in the history list instead of on the standard output. Each argument to the print command is treated as a single word in the history, regardless of its content.
> >
> > `-S`
> >
> > Place the results in the history list instead of on the standard output. In this case only a single argument is allowed; it will be split into words as if it were a full shell command line. The effect is similar to reading the line from a history file with the HIST_LEX_WORDS option active.
>
> See https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-print

Example of how it works:

[image]